# GWT iphone Facebook connect

Tags: iphone, facebook, gwt, cordova

I've been trying to implement **FacebookConnect** to my iPhone application built using **GWT** and **Phonegap (cordova)** (using [GwtFB](http://code.google.com/p/gwtfb/) library).

Facebook applications seem to require a URL to which it should redirect when the user succesfully logs in. For the iphone application there's no URL.

Can you advice me on how to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two tutorials:

https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect

http://www.drewdahlman.com/meusLabs/?p=88#more-88